# How to declare an array or list of sys.maxint size in python?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, list, out-of-memory

Let's say I need to work on N-queen problem with n being a 32-bit 
Integer. To cover the corner case of the maximum value of n, Python has sys.maxint available. But when I try to declare my array/ list with sys.maxint, I get a memory error.

```
from time import *
import sys
import numpy as np
import pdb 
# size of queen
pdb.set_trace()
n = sys.maxint

# recursive back tracing
ans = 0
#sol=np.array([0]*n)
sol2 = [0] * n
```

Comment: Does that really surprise you that you get a MemoryError if you try to allocate a list or array with `9223372036854775807` elements (64bit)? Even on a 32bit system it will be `2147483647` elements.

Comment: why do you need this ? this is not make sense. because the location that you want soo larger than normal pc memory limit.

Comment: How do you suggest me solving nqueen problem with n being as large as 32bit integer ? any pointers?

Comment: You could use `np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int8)` this will still take 2GB RAM (assuming `n=2147483647`) but you probably have that much :) But if you want an array containing `int32` you need at least 8GB RAM and for `int64` you would need 16GB RAM ... not really that much for modern computers but it could be that you don't have that much (then you need to buy more RAM).

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks alot for the pointers. I am thinking through it. I wonder, I have been given this assignment where I have to cover the case of 32bit integer. I believe though I cant test it my machine, the professor has a RAM of 16 gb or more :p
Will reconfirm though.